# ¿Como insertar registros en diferentes tablas con EF Core en ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

Tengo tres tablas una de usuarios que se relaciona de uno a muchos con una tabla agenda y esa se relaciona de muchos a uno con la tabla `tipo_telefono`, mi tabla agenda tiene el `id_agenda`, `id_usuario`, `id_tipo_telefono`, `telefono`.

Al crear mi modelo solo tengo las propiedades de mi usuario:

```
    public partial class Usuario
    {
        public Usuario()
        {
            Agenda = new HashSet<Agenda>();
        }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere del Curp")]
        public string Curp { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere del Nombre")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere del Apellido Paterno")]
        [Display(Name = " Apellido Paterno")]
        public string ApPat { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere del Apellido Materno")]
        [Display(Name = " Apellido Materno")]
        public string ApMat { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere de la contraseña")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
        public string Contrasena { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Tipo de Trabajador")]
        public int IdTipoTrabajor { get; set; }

        public TipoTrabajor IdTipoTrabajorNavigation { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Agenda> Agenda { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Agenda
    {
        public int IdAgenda { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public int IdTipoTelefono { get; set; }
        public string Curp { get; set; }

        public Usuario Curp1 { get; set; }
        public TipoTelefono IdTipoTelefonoNavigation { get; set; }
    }

//modelo nuevo que hice
public class UsuarioRegister
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere del Curp")]
        public string Curp { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere del Nombre")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere del Apellido Paterno")]
        [Display(Name = " Apellido Paterno")]
        public string ApPat { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere del Apellido Materno")]
        [Display(Name = " Apellido Materno")]
        public string ApMat { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere de la contraseña")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Contraseña")]
        public string Contrasena { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Tipo de Trabajador")]
        public int IdTipoTrabajor { get; set; }
        public TipoTrabajor IdTipoTrabajorNavigation { get; set; }
        public int IdAgenda { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Se requiere del Número")]
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Tipo de Telefono")]
        public int IdTipoTelefono { get; set; }
        public TipoTelefono IdTipoTelefonoNavigation { get; set; }

    }

//CONTROLADOR
 public ActionResult Add(UsuarioRegister user)
        {
            var usuario = new Usuario
            {
                Curp = user.Curp,
                Nombre = user.Nombre,
                ApPat = user.ApPat,
                ApMat = user.ApMat,
                Contrasena = user.Contrasena,
                IdTipoTrabajor = user.IdTipoTrabajor,
                IdTipoTrabajorNavigation = user.IdTipoTrabajorNavigation
            };

            var telefonos = new Agenda();
            _context.Usuario.Add(usuario);
            telefonos.Curp = usuario.Curp;
            _context.Agenda.Add(telefonos);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
```

No sé cómo usar mi `ICollection(Agenda)` para mostrar en la vista los campos a llenar de la agenda junto con todos los campos del usuario y cómo insertarlos en el controlador. Primero sería insertar los datos de la tabla agenda que son el teléfono que puso el usuario, el tipo de teléfono y el CURP del usuario y luego los datos del usuario en su tabla, pero cómo se pueden insertar en conjunto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nueva usando EF, ya busque la documentación pero sólo dice cómo mostrar los datos en conjunto de las tablas cuando ya se tienen registros relacionados.

Comment: buenas tardes Karla, ¿Podrías colocar el código que tienes en tu controlador donde ejecutas dicha idea? Saludos

Comment: fredyfx ya lo cambie, en la pregunta.

Comment: Me parece que además estás iniciando con ASP.net MVC, tengo un workshop de la versión 5 en https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY El código cambia entre ASP.net MVC y ASP.net  Core pero los conceptos son los mismos, ese workshop es la escencia de preguntas frecuentes sobre ASP.net MVC 5 que vi por estos lares, espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Lo veré, pero sigo sin entender bien como hacer lo que pregunte

Comment: Te recomiendo el uso de ViewModels para hacer esto que quieres, en teoría es algo similar a lo que ya hicistes con la clase UsuarioRegister donde creastes una clase con todos los datos que necesitas en tu formulario, y te recomiendo que revises tu esquema de bd puesto que no veo muy claras esas relaciones. saludos

Comment: Porque al momento de ya guardar el nuevo usuario, me sale error porque mi campo de teléfono, esta vació, porque no me esta guardando lo que ingreso en mi <input asp-for="Telefono" class="form-control" />  ?

Answer (score 1):

EF inserta todas las tablas relacionadas en el modelo E-R especificado sólo guardando el padre (el cuál tiene datos en la relación con el hijo) solo debes guardar el objeto padre.

1. agregar al contexto el objeto que tienes creado con el método Add.
2. salvar los cambios con SaveChanges().

   ```
       _context.Usuario.Add(usuario);            
       _context.SaveChanges();
   ```

pero tu usuario ya debe tener lleno el campo agenda (con su objeto compuesto completo), así como cada registro en teléfono debe estar agregado a la agenda igualmente.
es decir que al crear tu usuario:

```
       var usuario = new Usuario
        {
            Curp = user.Curp,
            Nombre = user.Nombre,
            ApPat = user.ApPat,
            ApMat = user.ApMat,
            Contrasena = user.Contrasena,
            IdTipoTrabajor = user.IdTipoTrabajor,
            IdTipoTrabajorNavigation = user.IdTipoTrabajorNavigation,
            Agenda = <<TU OBJETO QUE CONTIENE LA LISTA DE AGENDAS>>
        };
```

La relación entre telefono y agenda parece de llave foránea, así que esa tabla si deberías llenarla aparte. no se si sea lo que planeas, pero así parece.

```
public int IdTipoTelefono { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero puedes usar LINQ (o LAMBDA) para obtener los datos de tu modelo desde tu contextDB (Con solo filtrar por tu Usuario Entity Framework te traera ademas todas las Agendas asociadas)

entonces puedes hacer algo como:

```
  CargarUsuario(){
       Usuario consulta;
      using (var context = new contextDB())
      {
          consulta = context.Usuario.Where (s => s.IdTipoTrabajor == 4).FistOrDefault();
      }
      return consulta;
   }
```

Luego debes crear un ActionResult en tu controlador donde Obtienes la Instancia de tu objeto Usuario. Algo como:

```
    public ActionResult AltaUser()
    {
        Usuario user = CargarUsuario();

        return View("AltaUser", user);
    }
```

Luego debes crear una view Razor con Model de tipado estatico y pasandole el objeto Usuario creado (Puedes usar el Template de Create de VS):

```
   @model EjemploAgendaUsuario_EF.Models.Usuario
   <!-- SECCION AGENDA -->

    <!-- PARA MOSTRAR ALGUN DATO DE CADA AGENDA -->
    @foreach (var item in Model.Agenda)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(i => item.IdAgenda, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(i => item.IdAgenda, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => item.IdAgenda, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

El HTML Helper "EditorFor" te permite crear un input editable que luego puedes enviar al server con los nuevos datos a traves de un submit.

Answer (score 0):

Hola mira es sencillo pero debes de relacionar tus tablas asi cuando hagas el insert o update lo haga en cascada te dejo una respuesta que di hace un tiempo y explica como realizar el proceso a detalle si tienes dudas me escribes y te lo explico mejor.
saludos

[recuperando data relacionada con EF Core](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/440414/recuperando-data-relacionada-en-varios-niveles-con-entity-framework-core-3-1-o-s)