# Recuperando data relacionada en varios niveles con Entity Framework Core 3.1 o superior

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Aunque en la red hay información que te da guía para darle respuesta a esta pregunta, normalmente esta esta en ingles y esta distribuida en varios documentos, por lo que he decidido publicarla para que otros que buscan info en español tengan una idea.

Asumo que sabemos como relacionar vía entity framework las entidades y lo que vamos a tratar aquí es como recuperar toda la información.

problema tengo una estructura de clases así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como anticipe tenemos en el ContextBase configurado el entity de tal forma que están relacionadas
pero tengo el problema que no se como recuperar varios niveles es decir recuperar maestro - detalle es pan comido (solo son 2 niveles) pero en este caso son 5 niveles ¿Cómo puedo entonces hacer esto?.

Al leer documentación decía que no se podía, pero si se puede y más adelante lo veremos.
Esta Solución ha sido probada con EF Core 3.1 y 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debemos de tener las tablas relacionadas mas o menos en el context base verías algo así

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelb)
  {

       //Relación suceso->datosuceso 
       modelb.Entity<datosuceso>().HasOne(p => p.suceso)
       .WithMany(c => c.datosucesos)
       .HasForeignKey(p => p.IdSuceso);

       //Relación datosuceso->datocaracteristicosuceso 
       modelb.Entity<datocaracteristicosuceso>().HasOne(p => p.datosuceso)
       .WithMany(c => c.datocaracteristicosucesos)
       .HasForeignKey(p => p.IdDatoSuceso);

       //Datosucesoadif -> datosuceso
       modelb.Entity<datosucesoadif>().HasOne(f => f.datosuceso)
            .WithMany(t => t.datosucesoadifs).HasForeignKey(t => t.IdDatoSuceso);

       //FicheroSuceso -> datosuceso
       modelb.Entity<ficherosuceso>().HasOne(f => f.datosuceso)
            .WithMany(t => t.Ficherosucesos).HasForeignKey(p => p.IdDatoSuceso);

       //datosucesocaracteristicoadif -> datosuceso
       modelb.Entity<datocaracteristicosucesoadif>().HasOne(t => t.datosuceso)
            .WithMany(f => f.datocaracteristicosucesoadifs).HasForeignKey(p => p.IdDatoSuceso);

       //Datomattodante -> datosucesoadif
       modelb.Entity<datomatrodantesuceso>().HasOne(t => t.Datosucesoadif)
            .WithMany(f => f.Datomatrodantesucesos).HasForeignKey(p => p.IdDatosSucesoAdif);

       //Consecuenciasuseso -> datosucesoadif
       modelb.Entity<consecuenciasuceso>().HasOne(t => t.Datosucesoadif)
            .WithMany(f => f.Consecuenciasucesos).HasForeignKey(p => p.IdDatosSucesoAdif);

  }
```

No me detengo mucho en esto no es el objetivo pero entonces como hago la recuperación de toda la información, a continuacion el codigo con comentarios para explicarlo.

***///Aqui va el primer nivel la relación que incluye SUCESO Y DATOSUCESO (pueder ver la imagen arriba)
/// aqui todo facil maestro detalle con include***

```
                var rList = await iData.suceso.Include(a => a.datosucesos)
```

***///tercer nivel aqui vamos a agregar Datosucesoadif, ficherosuceso, etc. vamos a empezar
/// con datsucesoadif debido a que este tiene un cuarto nivel asi que ponemos un "ThenInclude(b => ///b.datosucesoadifs)" agregando este 3 nivel y luego otro "ThenInclude(c => c.Datomatrodantesucesos)"
/// que agrega un cuarto nivel***

```
                     .ThenInclude(b => b.datosucesoadifs).ThenInclude(c => c.Datomatrodantesucesos)
```

***///como tenemos que agregar otra tabla al cuarto nivel se hace colocando otro ThenInclude
/// pero este tiene algo especialc como puedes ver no puede hacerse como el primero porque sino
///Entity pensaria que es un quinto nivel y no es asi por eso le decimos que sigue siendo
/// el cuarto nivel de esta forma d.Datosucesoadif.Consecuenciasucesos***

```
                     .ThenInclude(d => d.Datosucesoadif.Consecuenciasucesos)
```

***///Agregar las otras del tercer nivel facilmente como lo pueden ver aqui***

```
                     .Include(a => a.datosucesos).ThenInclude(e => e.datocaracteristicosucesos)
                     .Include(a => a.datosucesos).ThenInclude(f => f.datocaracteristicosucesoadifs)
                     .Include(a => a.datosucesos).ThenInclude(g => g.Ficherosucesos)
```

***///miren aqui tenemos una tabla extra de esta forma podemos hacer llamadas de multiniveles***

```
                     .Include(a => a.datosucesos).ThenInclude(h => h.datosucesorebaseseñals).ToListAsync();
```

al final queda algo así

```
    namespace Infrastructure.Repository.Services
{
     public class ServiceSuceso : ServiceGeneric<suceso>, ISuceso
     {
          private readonly DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextBase> _OptionsBuilder;

          public ServiceSuceso()
          {
               _OptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContextBase>();
          }

          public async Task<List<suceso>> GetAllSucesos()
          {
               try
               {
                    using var iData = new ContextBase(_OptionsBuilder.Options);

                    var rList = await iData.suceso.Include(a => a.datosucesos)
                         .ThenInclude(b => b.datosucesoadifs).ThenInclude(c => c.Datomatrodantesucesos)
                         .ThenInclude(d => d.Datosucesoadif.Consecuenciasucesos)
                         .Include(a => a.datosucesos).ThenInclude(e => e.datocaracteristicosucesos)
                         .Include(a => a.datosucesos).ThenInclude(f => f.datocaracteristicosucesoadifs)
                         .Include(a => a.datosucesos).ThenInclude(g => g.Ficherosucesos)
                         .Include(a => a.datosucesos).ThenInclude(h => h.datosucesorebaseseñals).ToListAsync();

                    return rList;
               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                    return null;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Y espero que les sirva de algo como a mi me ha servido
saludos